# New window appears in messages

Tags: macbook-pro, messages

[image][image]Whenever one of my contacts replies to my message it appears in a separate window. Then all of my replies also appears in a separate window. There is no conversation stream in one window.
I've checked preferences and can find nothing to help.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?  Also, what specific MacBook Pro are you using and what OS? I am using the latest OS and I can't replicate your issue.  Any clarification you can provide would be great!

Comment: I have a new 16" running catalina OS 10.15.7.....I/m not sure how to add thumbnail of screen shot to this msg. ./Users/lucyhendricks/Desktop/Screen Shot 2020-10-10 at 2.11.07 PM.png

Comment: Click on "edit" at the bottom of your question. You can then add your screenshot.